# Laravel: Getting Session ID oddly truncates when using foreach

Tags: php, laravel, session, eloquent

So this is something a little weird... In Laravel 5.2, I'm trying to retrieve the id from the sessions database table. I'm using the default Sessions migration generated by Artisan.

Session.php (Session Model, this is all I have):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Session extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'sessions';
}
```

If I do `$sessions = Session::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();` and look through the nested arrays using `dd($sessions);`, the full ID shows up; for example `402de1fd4c6f3a9bda5d4f4c5980e5748dcddbde`. However, when I do

```
foreach($sessions as $session) {
    $id = $session->id;
}
```

doing `dd($id);` truncates to only the first digits before any letters in the string; in this example `402`. If there are no initial digits, `0` is returned instead.

Is there any reason why this would be happening? Unfortunately, since I'm not manipulating anything before running `dd` I cannot figure out what's going on with this string.

Comment: can you post your `Session` Model?

Comment: @z3r0ck Sure, I updated my question.

Comment: My initial thought was there might be a type casting in the Model.

But it's not the case. I am not sure why this is happening but the values you are getting behaves like it's being type cast to `int`.

Try adding this in your Model.

`protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'string',
  ];`

Comment: @z3r0ck Interesting, that worked. Thank you! I wonder what's going on behind the Laravel codebase that's causing this? Or is it maybe some type of odd PHP bug?

Comment: Behind the scene, laravel is casting all `id` attributes to `int` it seems.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `$session->id` it calls php magic method `__get` from your model then from that method it calls `getAttribute` method then `getAttributeValue` from `getAttributeValue` it calls some other methods after that it checks it `hasCast` then it calls `getCasts` from that method (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2769-L2778)

As you can see there for primary key it adds a default cast `int` so for your problem you can either `cast`

```
protected $casts = [ 'id' => 'string', ];//This part is taken from the comment of z3r0ck
```

or just add `$keyType`

```
protected $keyType = 'string';
```

Comment: Is there any documentation for the `$keyType` property? A link would be great if there is! Thanks!