# Laravel not outputting correct string

Tags: laravel

Laravel does not give me the correct string from the database, when i do a die and dump i get the following

[image]

The string i am wanting is:

```
"uid" => "35e_8d_89e"
```

However when i output the uid it displays as the following:

```
{{ $data->uid }}

35
```

It seems to be cutting the string short but i do not have any code to do that. any idea whats happening? Thanx in advance.

Comment: The dd function above is to show that the uid of the given variable is longer then 2 characters. my problem is its only showing 2 characters when i echo it out. im not sure what your comment is about...

Comment: mmm.. my mistake I undertand the question wrongly. so what type of data is uid? if it is integer then this is by laravel design to escaped the key.. try this {!! $data->uid !!}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyType is int, so it seems the string is truncated.

You can set the keyType to string in your model

```
protected $casts = [ 'uid' => 'string', ];
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38089965/laravel-getting-session-id-oddly-truncates-when-using-foreach) for an example of someone with a similar issue and the answer.